# How to change sub menu items color

Tags: css

I want to change color of sub menu in dropdown. Now it is white. When I change through customization both main and sub menu color changes. I only want to change sub menu color. How can I do that? My website is:

```
https://openwatersmarine.com.au
```

I used this CSS but it does not worked:

```
.primary-menu-ul .sub-menu{
color: blue;
}
```

This is a wordpress website.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You need to provide your HTML as well

Comment: This is wordpress website

Comment: In the Developer Console you can find the actual elements you need to modify.

Comment: I have tried but did not recognize which class to target

Comment: @ans11 Wordpress sites use HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and it worked for me.

```
.row .primary-menu-ul .sub-menu li a{
    color: blue;
}
```